# Eventp 'click' dentro de forEach me multiplica los elementos del NodeList dependiendo el largo de este

Tags: javascript

Tengo un `NodeList` de botones que se generan dinamicanmente, el `querySelectoAll` lo tomo sin problemas, al recorrer y mostrar todos los elementos en el `ForEach` lo muestra correctamente, pero cuando le agrego un evento a cada boton de ese `forEach` si muestro el `e.currentTarget`, no importa cual le de me muestra ese Nodo multiplicado

```
function agregarArticulos () {

    let item;
       

        agregarBtns.forEach(function(btn, posicion) {
      
        btn.addEventListener("click", () => {

            alert.classList.add("hidden");

            if (listaArticulos.length > 4) {
            alert.classList.remove("hidden");
            return;
            } 
                
           
            


            item = document.createElement("tr");
            item.className = "item";
            item.innerHTML = `    <td class="name-title name">`+ names[posicion].textContent +`</td>
            <td class="code-title code">`+ codes[posicion].textContent +`</td>
            <td class="price-title title-first price-item">`+ prices[posicion].textContent +` <i class="fas fa-trash btn-trash"></i>  </td>`
            table.appendChild(item);
        
            listaArticulos.push(item);  

            
            if(listaArticulos.length > 0) {
                
                carritoBtn.classList.remove("hidden");

            }

            const btnsEliminar = document.querySelectorAll(".fas");
            const itemList = document.querySelectorAll(".item");

           eliminarArticulo();

            function eliminarArticulo() { //ESTA ES

                btnsEliminar.forEach((btn,index) => {
                        console.log("****")
                     
                    btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {

                       console.log(e.currentTarget);

                        /* table.removeChild(itemList[index]);
                        listaArticulos.length-- */

                    })
                })
            };
            
                
        });
    
    }); 

};
```

Comment: Puedes compartir el html?

Comment: `agregarBtns` parece ser un array o algo iterable, ahi es donde deben estar repetidos los elementos.